# How can i do that in gmail adress cannot be two or more "."(points)?

Tags: bash

I have to write something in my if clause, but I don't know how to write it. For example "hello..hello@gmail.com" or "hello.hello.hello@gmail.com" should be invalid inputs, but "hello.hello@gmail.com" should be valid.

```
read -p  "enter email " email;

if [[ "$email" =~ ^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+[A-Za-z]+@[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-$
echo "Email address $email is valid."//my if clause, which checks if there is correct gmail

else 

echo "Email address $email is invalid."

fi
```

Comment: Combining so many `+`'s in your expression will make it really slow. Better: `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+\.?[A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+@...`

Comment: The logic I'm after is that the second `[...]` group already allows for a letter in the second position, so you don't need `+` on the first group. Then I added `\.?` once to say there's an optional dot, and since I only put it in there once, that's be maximum.

Comment: Better: `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+)?@...` to have the third group only kick in if there actually is a dot.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you aware of this: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```regex
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+)?@[A-Za-z]+(\.[A-Za-z]+)+$
```

Key ideas:

- `\.` allows one dot
- `(...)?` says that group with the dot is optional, so no dots is also OK
- minimize the number of different ways the same string can get parsed, for efficiency
- I assume the domain can have multiple dots, but you can also use `...@[A-Za-z]+.[A-Za-z]+$ to allow exactly one dot in the domain.